# DSolve in V 13.1 hangs on many ode's when using IncludeSingularSolutions->True. How to work around this?

Tags: differential-equations, version-13.1

V 13.1 introduced the option [IncludeSingularSolutions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IncludeSingularSolutions.html)

When trying it, so far I have found over 250 ode's which hangs when using this option. First and second order. At the bottom I've put a link to plain .m file that contains list of ode's that hang and also link to a more complete notebook that shows more examples.

I do not mean `DSolve` just takes longer time now to finish, but I mean really hangs. I've waited for more than one hr on some and `DSolve`  was still running.

Without this option, `DSolve` would otherwise finish almost instantly.

My question is: Is there an option to set a timelimit on finding the Singular solution, so that if it can't find it within this time, to simply ignore this option? Similar to

```
 "IntegrateOptions" /. SystemOptions[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where one can set a timelimit on some options so not to cause the whole command to hang or take more time than wanted.

And why it seem to always hang when the solution of the ode has `ProductLog` in it. But I have found cases where it also hang when the solution has no  `ProductLog` but these are much less common.

This is unfortunate, since now it means one has to try this option not knowing in advanced if the long time being taken and the reason for the timeout and failure of `DSolve` is because it could not find the singular solution and not because it could not find the general solution (which it can find). This option should be able to quickly decide if there is singular solution or not and not hang trying to find it.

Here is an example

```
ode=y'[x]==(1+x+y[x])^(1/2);
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->False],60]];
Print["time used ",sol[[1]],"\nsolution =",sol[[2]]];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->True],60]];
Print["time used ",sol[[1]],"\nsolution =",sol[[2]]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is another

```
ode=-(a*(-y[x]+x*y'[x])^r)+y''[x]==0;
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->False],60]];
Print["time used ",sol[[1]],"\nsolution =",sol[[2]]];
sol=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->True],60]];
Print["time used ",sol[[1]],"\nsolution =",sol[[2]]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is another

```
ode = (y[x] + 3*x - 1)^2*y'[x] - (2*y[x] - 1)*(4*y[x] + 6*x - 3) == 
   0;
sol = AbsoluteTiming[
   TimeConstrained[
    DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> False], 60]];
Print["time used ", sol[[1]], "\nsolution =", sol[[2]]];
sol = AbsoluteTiming[
   TimeConstrained[
    DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True], 60]];
Print["time used ", sol[[1]], "\nsolution =", sol[[2]]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Links**

[m file that contains list of odes](https://12000.org/tmp/dsolve_hangs_on_singular_solution/list_of_odes_that_hang_in_mma_13_1.m)

[notebook showing more examples](https://12000.org/tmp/dsolve_hangs_on_singular_solution/example_odes_that_hang.nb)

[Current DSolve test report](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/CAS_ode_tests/index.htm)

Comment: Moreover, `DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]], y, x]` produces a wrong solution `{{y -> Function[{x}, -x + 2 ProductLog[-E^(-(3/2) - x/2 - C[1]/2)] + 
     ProductLog[-E^(-(3/2) - x/2 - C[1]/2)]^2]}}` in view of  `y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]] /. %;% /. {C[1] -> 1, x -> 1}` which results in `{False}`.

Comment: If you replace `ProductLog[z]` by `ProductLog[k, z]` in the solution to `y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + x + y[x]]`, as hinted at by the warning from `Solve`, one finds domains over which the altered solution is valid for `k` a nonzero integer. For `k == 0`, the solution seems to satisfy the ode only at `x - C[1] - 1 == 0` (in the complex plane), which is not much of a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overloading the internal function with the Villegas-Gayley trick:

```
DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions[];
Internal`InheritedBlock[{DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions},
 (*****)
 DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions // Unprotect;
 DownValues@DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions = Join[
   {HoldPattern[
      call : DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in]] :> 
     Block[{$in = True},
      TimeConstrained[call,
       If[NumericQ@$singularSolutionsTimeConstraint,
        $singularSolutionsTimeConstraint,
        Infinity],
       {}]
      ]},
   DownValues@DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions];
 DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions // Protect;
 (*****)
 PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity};
 ode = y'[x] == (1 + x + y[x])^(1/2);
 sol = AbsoluteTiming[
   Block[{$singularSolutionsTimeConstraint = 2}, 
    DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]]
   ];
 Print["time used ", sol[[1]], "\nsolution =", sol[[2]]]
 ]
```

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
> ```
>
> time used 2.069711
>
> ```
> solution = {
>  {y[x] -> -x + 2*ProductLog[-E^(-3/2 - x/2 - C[1]/2)] + 
>     ProductLog[-E^(-3/2 - x/2 - C[1]/2)]^2}}
> ```

Comment: Note (in response to a comment I just saw): I believe the fail-expression in `TimeConstrained`, which I specified as `{}` which is what ``DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions`` returns when it fails, may be replaced by `{{y[x] -> "Failed"}}` —  `$Failed` is not good because `FreeQ[result, $Failed]` is used in higher-level functions to test the result of internal ones. However, `{{y[x] -> Failure["TimeConstraint", <||>]}}` seems to work.

Comment: -1. Sorry, `-x + 2 ProductLog[-E^(-(3/2) - x/2 - C[1]/2)] +       ProductLog[-E^(-(3/2) - x/2 - C[1]/2)]^2]` is not any solution of ` y'[x] == (1 + x + y[x])^(1/2)` (see my comment to the question). The verification is very useful.

Comment: @user64494 [That's what ***I*** said.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270586/dsolve-in-v-13-1-hangs-on-many-odes-when-using-includesingularsolutions-true/270590#comment675384_270586). Don't be so thoughtless, and try to stay on topic. The problem is to time-constrain solving for the singular solution, not to fix the ordinary general solution of `DSolve`. Your downvote is unethical.

Answer (score 9):

Evaluate this:

```
$ModifyDSolve=True;
Unprotect[DSolve];
DSolve[eqns_,u_Symbol,opts___?OptionQ]:=Block[{$ModifyDSolve},TimeConstrained[
   DSolve[eqns,u,opts],
   600,
   DSolve[eqns,u,Flatten@{IncludeSingularSolutions->False,opts}]
]]/;And[$ModifyDSolve,IncludeSingularSolutions/.Flatten[{opts,Options@DSolve}]];
Protect[DSolve]
```

That should make DSolve start over with  IncludeSingularSolutions->False  after trying with  IncludeSingularSolutions->True for 10 minutes. I learned this Block trick from tech support at Wolfram Research about 25 years ago!

Comment: Thanks. But I am already doing this using a simple `If` statement. Like this `res=AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[DSolve[{ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->True],3*60]];
If[res[[2]] === $Aborted,
 res = AbsoluteTiming[TimeConstrained[
    DSolve[{ode,y[x],xIncludeSingularSolutions -> False], 3*60]]
 ]` But both these methods means one have to now always try `DSovle` 2 times. Wasting lots of time even though the first time the general solution (most likely) was found already, which means having to find it again....

Comment: .... A better solution would have been that Mathematica returns the general solution (assuming it can) and $Failed in the slot where the singular solution would be. Something like `{{the solution here},{$Failed}}` so one does not have to try again. They can read the general solution, and check if the last slot was $Failed or not, then they know if the singular solution was found or not. Then there is no need to try again. Now my test takes almost 50% more time than it needs to be due to this. almost 2 days.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for reporting about this issue. The slow evaluation arises because `DSolve` uses several different methods to generate all possible singular solutions, and some of them can be time expensive. We are already working to fix this issue.